reconstruct a signal - help with understanding a question
I need your help with the following question:

I can see tht there is kind of a convolution here together with sampling, but I can not understand how to solve it. It is quite difficult for me to see the sampling since there is no summation here (or a multiplication by an impulse train)
Thank you in advance!

Is this homework? Then please tag it as such, show your work so far and where exactly you are stuck. I strongly recommend reading up on the Sampling Theorem and how exactly it was derived.
